# Passing additional parameters to Rails Generate Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I'm running Rails 3 on Ruby 1.9.2.

I want to create a model, so I looked at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) to get the table definition that I want, but I wonder how I would pass this to rails generate model?

Basically I want this:

```
title :string, :null => false
details :text, :limit => 30000, :null => false
```

But I can only specify the column name and type, not :null or :limit.

I've tried `rails model generate Article (title:string, :null => false) (details:text, :limit=>30000, :null => false)` but that just tells me that ( is an unexpected token.

If I just generate the model with title:string details:text then the article.rb file is empty, presumably because it's read from the DB anyway.

As everything in Rails is supposed to be a) simple and b) magic, I'm wondering if I'm just missing something and have to pass something like a hash to generate model? Or do I really have to manually edit the migration .rb file?

Comment: You have to edit it manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you do have to manually edit the migration file for that. The generator just offers a starting point, it does not do everything.

Doing this in the migration file is very easy anyway.

```
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.string :title, :null => false
  t.text   :details, :limit => 3000, :null => false
end
```

Comment: This took me forever to track down. Ive been searching all over for how to do the limit in my `rails g scaffold...` thank you!

Answer (score 19):

As it turns out, the limit can (now) be specified in the command line:

```
rails generate model user pseudo:string{30}
```

**Source:** [usage doc from Rails GitHub project](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/USAGE)

Setting the default, however, still appears to require editing the migration manually.

For additional migration options, see [the official Rails migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: WOW! this answer is so right. How could I show the doc from command line? rails help model?

Answer (score 7):

Try some tricks: belongs_to and index

```
rails g model User username:string:index group:belongs_to
```

This will create:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible :username
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `"null".to_sym => false` in your **rails generate model**.
For example:

```
rails g model client 'ClientName, "null".to_sym => false:string{100}'
```

This will turn the **"null"** into a symbol, allowing it to run properly when running `db:migrate`